# A Python function did not work correctly when run on multiple cores, but runs normally on a single core

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

This function did not work correctly when `n_jobs!=1`

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

def foo(n_jobs):

    result = {}

    x = np.sin(4 * np.pi * np.arange(0, 1, 0.001))
    y = np.sin(8 * np.pi * np.arange(0, 1, 0.001) + np.pi/2)

    x2yT = np.zeros(x.shape[0])
    y2xT = np.zeros(x.shape[0])
    
    def parallelize(ite):
        
        xi = x[ite] * 2
        yi = y[ite] + 1
        y2xT[ite] = xi
        x2yT[ite] = yi

    r = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs)(delayed(parallelize)(i) for i in np.arange(x.shape[0]))

    result[f'y2xT'] = y2xT
    result[f'x2yT'] = x2yT
    return pd.DataFrame(result)
```

The following code snippet produces a plot using a function `foo` with a single core:

```
r0 = foo( n_jobs = 1)
r0.plot()
```

The resulting plot is shown below:

[image: A].

The following code snippet produces a plot using a function `foo` with multiple cores:

```
r0 = foo( n_jobs = -1)
r0.plot()
```

The resulting plot is shown below:

[image: B]

How can I ensure that the function utilizes multiple cores correctly

Comment: Paralellize runs the jobs in multiple processes.  Changes made to y2xT and x2yT in those other processes never make it back to the process on which you are doing the plotting.  Look at https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/parallel_memmap.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-parallel-memmap-py for info on sharing a numpy array across threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment from Frank, I tried to convert `y2xT` and `x2yT` from `numpy.ndarray` to `numpy.memmap`, and it works!

```
def foo(n_jobs):

    result = {}
        
    x = np.sin(4 * np.pi * np.arange(0, 1, 0.001))
    y = np.sin(8 * np.pi * np.arange(0, 1, 0.001) + np.pi/2)


    # x2yT = np.zeros(x.shape[0])
    # y2xT = np.zeros(x.shape[0])
    
    x2yT = np.memmap('x2yT.pkl', dtype=np.float32, shape=x.shape[0], mode='w+')
    y2xT = np.memmap('y2xT.pkl', dtype=np.float32, shape=x.shape[0], mode='w+')
    
    def parallelize(ite):
        
        xi = x[ite] * 2
        yi = y[ite] + 1
        y2xT[ite] = xi
        x2yT[ite] = yi

    r = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs)(delayed(parallelize)(i) for i in np.arange(x.shape[0]))

    result[f'y2xT'] = y2xT
    result[f'x2yT'] = x2yT


    return pd.DataFrame(result)

r0 = foo( n_jobs = -1)
r0.plot()
```